# Proving $(5-\frac5k )(1+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}) \le 5 - \frac{5}{k+1}$

Tags: inequality, induction

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? need to prove for $k\ge2$
$$(5-\frac5k )(1+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}) \le 5 - \frac{5}{k+1}$$$$(5-\frac5k )(1+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2})= 5(1-\frac1k)(1+\frac1{(k+1)^2})$$
$$=5(1+\frac1{k+1)^2}-\frac1k-\frac1{k(k+1)^2})$$
$$= 5(1-\frac{k^2+k+2}{k(k+1)^2})$$
$$=5(1-\frac{k(k+1)}{k(k+1)^2}+\frac2{k(k+1)^2})$$
$$=5(1-\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac2{k(k+1)^2})$$
$$= 5 - \frac5{k+1}+\frac{10}{k(k+1)^2}\le5-\frac5{k+1}$$
which doesn't look true.

Comment: Your method would have worked, except for when you missed a minus sign before the last term in the third last row.

Comment: Are you sure? because $$\frac{k(k+1)}{k(k+1)^2}-\frac2{k(k+1)^2} = \frac{k^2+k-2}{k(k+1)^2}$$ isn't it? maybe I am being dumb.

Comment: That's correct.  However you do not have $k^2 + k - 2$ in the numerator, you have $k^2 + k + 2$ in the previous line.  Just trace the signs in front of $2$, you should see the error.  BTW, this is not proof by induction - I hope you were not asked specifically for that.

Comment: Right, but I don't have a -2 in the third last row. I have $+\frac2{k(k+1)^2}$ I am not seeing the error. Also, the induction step is what led me here, so I need to prove this to prove the induction.

Comment: You are missing it again. You need to distribute the "-" sign for all terms in the numerator.  Noticed someone has shown the error in red below... Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't consider my short, simple and correct answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your process is correct until the 4th step. There is a sign error in the 5th step. Gigili's answer provides the correct solution, but if you are still stumped about where the minus sign is coming from, here is a more detailed look at all the manipulations and properties involved to get from the 4th step in your process to the correct 5th step (which is the 4th step in Gigili's answer).

$$\eqalignno{
&\phantom{=}\thinspace 5\left(1 -{k^2 + k + 2\over k{(k + 1)}^2} \right)&(1)\cr
&=5\left(1 + \left(-{k^2 + k + 2\over k{(k + 1)}^2}\right) \right)&(2)\cr
&=5\left(1 + \left(-1\left({k^2 + k + 2\over k{(k + 1)}^2}\right)\right) \right)&(3)\cr
&=5\left(1 + \left(-1\left({k(k + 1) + 2\over k{(k + 1)}^2}\right)\right) \right)&(4)\cr
&=5\left(1 + \left(-1\left({k(k + 1)\over k{(k + 1)}^2} + {2\over k{(k + 1)}^2}\right)\right) \right)&(5)\cr
&=5\left(1 + \left(\biggl(-1\biggr)\left({k(k + 1)\over k{(k + 1)}^2}\right) + \biggl(-1\biggr)\left( {2\over k{(k + 1)}^2}\right)\right) \right)&(6)\cr
&=5\left(1 + \left(\left(-{k(k + 1)\over k{(k + 1)}^2}\right) + \left(- {2\over k{(k + 1)}^2}\right)\right)\right)&(7)\cr
&=5\left(1 + \left(-{k(k + 1)\over k{(k + 1)}^2}\right) + \left(- {2\over k{(k + 1)}^2}\right)\right)&(8)\cr
&=5\left(1 - {k(k + 1)\over k{(k + 1)}^2} - {2\over k{(k + 1)}^2} \right)&(9)\cr
}$$

(1) Given (4th step in the incorrect solution / 3rd step in Gigili's answer).
(2) Definition of subtraction in terms of addition.
(3) Multiplication property of negative one.
(4) Associative property of addition; factoring.
(5) Addition of fractions with like denominators.
(6) Distributive property.
(7) Multiplication property of negative one.
(8) Associative property of addition.
(9) Definition of subtraction in terms of addition (similar to 5th step in the incorrect solution, but with correct sign / 4th step in Gigili's answer).

Answer (score 2):

$$=5(1+\frac1{(k+1)^2}-\frac1k-\frac1{k(k+1)^2})$$
$$=5(1+\frac{k}{k(k+1)^2}-\frac{(k+1)^2}{k(k+1)^2}-\frac1{k(k+1)^2})$$
$$= 5(1-\frac{k^2+k+2}{k(k+1)^2})$$
$$=5(1-\frac{k(k+1)}{k(k+1)^2}\color{red}{-}\frac2{k(k+1)^2})$$
$$=5(1-\frac{1}{k+1}\color{red}{-}\frac2{k(k+1)^2})$$
$$= 5 - \frac5{k+1}\color{red}{-10}\frac1{k(k+1)^2}$$

---

Where $k \geq 2$ , so $$\frac{-10}{k(k+1)^2} < 0$$
Therefore

$$5 - \frac5{k+1}-\frac{10}{k(k+1)^2} \leq 5 - \frac5{k+1}$$

---

$$(5-\frac5k )(1+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}) \le 5 - \frac{5}{k+1}$$ Which is the desired result.

Comment: Sorry, Macavity mentioned the same thing, I dont get why $$\frac{k^2+k+2}{k(k+1)^2}) =\frac{k(k+1)}{k(k+1)^2}-\frac2{k(k+1)^2}$$ isn't $$\frac{k(k+1)}{k(k+1)^2}-\frac2{k(k+1)^2} = \frac{k^2+k-2}{k(k+1)^2}$$ which would make the previous step false?

Comment: @user60334: If you follow the steps, you'll get it. There was a minus sign that you forgot to apply while separating the fraction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = (5-\frac{5}{x})(1+\frac{1}{(1+x)^2})-5+\frac{5}{1+x}$. After a little algebra, this gives $f(x) = -\frac{10}{x(x+1)^2}$. Hence $f(x) \leq  0$ when $x>0$.

Hence $f(k) \leq 0$ for $k \geq 2$.